# How to manage @todo programming stuff?

Tags: java, javadoc, project-management

For many years my code was full of this kind of comments :

```
//TODO : Add ...
...
/*
 *TODO : Fix ...
 *
 */
```

Now I think to create my own [`@todo`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/taglet/overview.html) javadoc annotation ... but before doing that I want to know if do you guys have better way to manage your *todo* programming stuff ?

Comment: This can be language agnostic...

Comment: annotations are not language agnostic...

Comment: @Martinho & TofuBeer : It's source code comment ... in most cases it's tight to the language ... but in "multilangage" projects an agnostic solution like the IDE one can be very good...

Comment: I like "@TODO" in a comment (as appropriate for the language). By staying consistent, they can be grep'ed and counted.

Comment: I wrote http://srcoftruth.com for this purpose

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans, ..) has a tasks plugin, which detects all `TODO`s and shows them in a list. In Eclipse it's `Window > Show View > Other > Tasks`

In Netbeans, it is `Window > Action Items`  (CTRL+6)

No need to write your own annotation.

Comment: In NetBeans it is Action Items

Answer (score 41):

TODO statements carry the risk of being left in the code forever, which is bad because  `// TODO elaborate answer`

Comment: Its better than having the actual issue/problem left in the code forever

Comment: @OliverWatkins I agree. TODO has at least two advantages: it identifies something as a pending issue, and it is easy to search for. Despite of this, I've seen dozens of TODO comments which had been never "solved" by their authors. To me, this is just unfinished work.

Comment: I usually write a ticket number next to TODO, so anyone who stumbles upon the code, while doing some other task, will see which technical debt is present at this place. It makes it easier to analyze how it may affect the task completion (e.g. that you have to finish this technical debt, or that your task may be rejected as much harder than estimated). If there are no TODOs in the code, then you may be unaware of technical debt that you've completed while doing some business requirement.

Comment: This is awesome.

Comment: Don't blame the "TODO", blame the author who was supposed to fix that TODO. If you remove the "TODO" the original issue will probably never be fixed.

Comment: @OliverWatkins I totally agree with you now. I think my April 2010 answer and my May 2015 comment were too strict. Actually, if there's something important to do, writing it in the code may make sense.

Answer (score 14):

I basically use three systems for different kinds of TODO items:

- Paper notepad for short-term items (like today or this week)
- TODO comments plus IDE support (e.g. Eclipse Tasks view) for smaller, longer-term items
- Issue tracker like Trac plus IDE support (e.g Mylyn) for more complex, longer-term items

Comment: +1 for the issue tracker (and the paper!)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe Doxygen can help you?

Doxygen recognise those ///@TODO:s and creates a list with them.

And since Doxygen can use Javadoc style comments, I guess it is kind of easy to try it.

Answer (score 6):

I would not use a `@todo` javadoc annotation because IMO it should'nt go into the documentation.
Documentation should be *public*, not ideal for TODOs.
TODOs should also go near the code they relate to, an advantage of using comments.

Answer (score 5):

For vim there is also this [Tasklist](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2607) script, inspired by Eclipse's task list, which scrapes for TODO, FIXME, etc. in your text files and displays them as a list in an extra buffer (see [screenshot](http://axisym3.net/jdany/vim-plugins/#tasklist)).

Answer (score 3):

I use FIX! instead of TODO. The number of exclamation points indicates the priority.  IntelliJ lets you set up custom filters for these, so I can look at level-3 "FIX!!!" comments and tackle those.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Maven, you could use the [taglist-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/taglist-maven-plugin/) to scans the source files for tags (any tag you want, this is configurable) and generates [a report](http://www.mojohaus.org/taglist-maven-plugin/taglist.html) on their occurrences.

> The Taglist Maven Plugin 
>   generates a report on various tags
>   found in the code, like `@todo` or
>   `//TODO` tags

But tracking tags is the easy part, fixing them is a bit harder and takes more time :)

Comment: +1 : I just sow a sample report : really interesting !!

Answer (score 2):

For small tasks such as my usual //todo I use local tasks in Eclipse Mylyn, for bigger tasks (even if I think those might be called features or bugs) I use Trac; if you find your code full of TODOs it's time to get a ticket management system.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use find and grep to search for those keywords in your projects

Answer (score 2):

problem with todo flags is the same as with warnings (e.g. java compiler, checkstyle). if they appear to often, you will ignore them. in your case i would track them through a report by a build-system (e.g. maven or ant). at the end of each iteration you should make a rule, that the number of todo flags decreases.

less todo-flags means:

- solving them
- delete them because they got obsolete (which happens often if you never tidy up code)

generally don't use todo flags for all tasks. for me they are just little reminders or refactorings-todos. bigger tasks should always be tracked by a ticket-system (like trac or jira).

Comment: We used a plug-in for Hudson that showed the TODOs over time - it's public and visible, meaning there's more drive to reduce it over time.

Answer (score 2):

TODO is fine in a small team, but if you open-source project or widen the developer access in any way, the other variants like TO_DO, fixme, XXX, NOTE, HACK, bug, "your_defect_tool_here" and so on need scanning for anyway. 
A bit heavyweight, but my TODO protocol would look like:

TODO:yy-mm-dd:author:your_comment

Lastly make the comment you do leave strategic, not a design statement or opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If your TODO statements are bugging you that much and causing you that much angst when seeing them I'd write a small script in the build process that detects and fails the compilation.  Have it fail in the same way that it fails on warning statements.